# Does await keyword wait indefinitely or does it have a limit?

Tags: c#, async-await

If you use the await keyword does it have any limits or does it wait indefinitely for the task to complete?

EDIT: The full context I have is...

A frontend application issues a non async HTTP request to an async Web API endpoint. Ultimately the endpoint will await a call to a stored proc on a db. The frontend application hits a HTTP timeout after probably 100 seconds. If the proc takes 35 minutes to complete,

1. Will the await method wait 35 minutes for the proc to complete or are there limits?
2. What happens the await call when the HTTP timeout completes after 100 seconds?
3. if it continues to run, what happens when the proc returns a response after 35 minutes?

Comment: I feel there's something more to this question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: a `Task` per definition is just a piece of work. It does not know anything about a time-limit nor anything else, only that it's been started and that it eventually terminates.

Comment: `await` will await indefinitely but cancelling an `await` after a while is no guarantee that the actual operation will stop. Given that network calls are asynchronous anyway, what does `request to an async Web API endpoint.` mean? You may have to not just cancel waiting but notify the API to cancel its operation

Comment: What does `async Web API endpoint` mean? RPC-style? Or did you get a Job/request token that can be used to retrieve the results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`await` will wait indefinitely unless the operation itself cancels. While you can cancel that using a CancellationTokenSource or `Task.WaitAsync` that won't stop the asynchronous operation itself.

In the question's case :

1. `await` will keep waiting but
2. The client's HTTP request will timeout, so `await` will end with a timeout exception
3. The endpoints won't notice anything and the stored procedure will keep running for 35 minutes.
4. Any results will be lost since the client is no longer waiting for them

If you want to actually cancel the stored procedure you'll have to modify the endpoint to handle a cancellation request and somehow cancel the stored procedure

One way to do this would be to signal the worker code that executes the stored procedure to cancel. Cancelling an `ExecuteNonQuery` call wont' cancel the stored procedure itself, but if the code runs with an explicit database transaction, the cancellation exception will abort the transaction and the stored procedure.

Another option is to kill the database session that executes the stored procedure. This will require some bookkeeping, to store the session ID of the executing connection before the call to `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Stephen Toub describes these implications in [How do I cancel non-cancelable async operations?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/). The conclusion is

> So, can you cancel non-cancelable operations? No.  Can you cancel waits on non-cancelable operations?  Sure… just be very careful when you do.

**What about asynchronous Web APIs?**

To paraphrase Simon Wardley `What does this mean` ?

**ASP.NET Web APIs with `async` actions?**

Those are still RPC-style APIs that just allow the action to use the `async` keyword. If the client times out, it won't be able to receive results

**Request-Reply style**

In this case the client, eg an Angular or Reactjs SPA sends a request to the server and after half an hour the server sends a reply to the client using WebSockets or SignalR.

That's truly asynchronous and the response won't be lost. This requires a different client design, separating the request from the response code. Quite often that can *simplify* the client though, as the request code no longer has to handle timeout failure cases.

With a bit of care, responses can be sent through SignalR to specific Client/User  IDs, not just the requesting client, so that even if the browser closes in the mean time, a new client could receive the results.

Other technologies that can be used for this are Server-Sent events and Push API notifications.

**Polling for status**

Not very scalable for either client or server. In this case the client starts a request, eg a job and gets back a token. The client polls the server for the job's status. That's very expensive on server resources.

Comment: Thank you for this. The answers you gave in points 1,3,4 above were what I was guessing would happen but I'm surprised at point 2. I would have thought whatever web server thread handling the request on the Web API side would exist independent of the HTTP request that initiated it...that basically the await would simply do it's job but any results would be lost to the client who is no longer waiting for them.

Comment: Imagine the request (non async) is initiated from an Angular application to an asynchronous .NET Framework Web API endpoint...which then drills down to make an async call to execute a sproc on a db... I thought that handover to the webserver would start a thread which lived independently of the HTTP call initiated by the Angular application. thought being the operative word here :)

Comment: Which timeout are you talking about though? The client's or the server's? If the client's, it's the same as what you thought - the server doesn't care what the client is doing. If you mean the *server*, the timeout refers to the server operation, not the thread. If the operation times out and throws an exception, this would also rollback any active db transactions and kill any connections, at least if the code is well written

Comment: What does `asynchronous .NET Framework Web API endpoint` mean? That the action has the `async` keyword? That's not really asynchronous then. It's a plain old RPC-style operation that just allows the use of `await` in the method. It still won't care about the client aborting or closing

Comment: I understand. I was talking about the client timing out. Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: "What does asynchronous .NET Framework Web API endpoint mean? That the action has the async keyword? That's not really asynchronous then." ... it's as you said, just a controller with a method decorated with the async keyword.

Comment: If the client times out the Web API action will keep running but the Angular SPA won't be able to get the results. You can fix this if you use eg SignalR or Websockets instead so the server sends the response to the client. That's *far* more scalable too. OTOH it's a lot easier to do this with ASP.NET Core than .NET Framework

Comment: If you use SignalR/websockets the SPA code would be simpler too - you'd be able to listen for server events and update the UI no matter when they arrived

Comment: @Fred2020 how much control do you have over the API? There are several ways you can push notifications to Angular, not just SignalR. Although that's probably the easiest, especially if you can't use ASP.NET Core

Comment: I have full control over the API, except for upgrading it to .NET Core unfortunately

Answer (score 8):

The `await` keyword waits indefinitely. There is no limit in the awaiting. For example the `await` below will never proceed to the next line of code. The execution flow will get stuck forever in the `await`.

```
await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite);
throw new UnreachableException(); // This line is unreachable.
```

Starting from .NET 6, the `Task` and `Task<TResult>` types have a [`WaitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitasync) method, that returns a new task which completes after a specified `TimeSpan timeout`. In case the `timeout` elapses before the completion of the base task, the `WaitAsync` task propagates a `TimeoutException`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So the answer to the first question is, it will wait indefinitely. Is the awaiting affected by the initiating HTTP request timing out before the await task completes? If not, when the task completes after 35 minutes what happens?